# Android App Which Targets API21, needs AppCompat?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am going to build a new app, targeting API21 and higher, do I need AppCompat v7 or I can omit it?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what features you want to implement and which functionalities you want to develop. Targeting API level and minimum API level are both different thing. Your selection of support libraries depends upon your your minimum API level, that is defined by `minSdkVersion`.

You can decide and derive below conclusion from official [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html):

## v4 Support Library

This library is designed to be used with Android 2.3 (API level 9) and higher. It includes the largest set of APIs compared to the other libraries, including support for application components, user interface features, accessibility, data handling, network connectivity, and programming utilities.

## v7 Libraries

There are several libraries designed to be used with Android 2.3 (API level 9) and higher. These libraries provide specific feature sets and can be included in your application independently from each other.

## v7 AppCompat library

This library adds support for the Action Bar user interface design pattern.

Note: This library depends on the v4 Support Library. If you are using Ant or Eclipse, make sure you include the v4 Support Library as part of this library's classpath.

## v13 Support Library

This library is designed to be used for Android 3.2 (API level 13) and higher. It adds support for the Fragment user interface pattern with the (FragmentCompat) class and additional fragment support classes.